# somehow paste to random location ... tell vim to always ignore any roller actions from mouse middle roller button

Tags: cut-copy-paste, mouse

I have been using vi or vim for many years however recently ( past year or two ) when I paste some highlighted text vim seems to paste highlighted text ( more often than not ) to random location in the file ... I paste by hitting mouse middle roller button and I think vim is poorly handling the paste by sensing a minute amount of roller action during the press down in the mouse middle roller button during the paste action

Here is my cat ~/.vimrc

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim


set ts=4
set ic

syntax on

"  to shut off paste indent
se paste


"  to disable paste moving mouse paste location
"  mouse=r
"   above fails:   E492: Not an editor command: mouse=r
"  mouse=v
"   above ALSO fails:   E492: Not an editor command: mouse=r



"  If this does not work, a common problem is not having ownership of your ~/.viminfo file. If this is the case, then sudo chown user:group ~/.viminfo
" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
 au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

Notice commented above two attempts to fix this

Please note this never happened before a year or two ago ... since then its almost useless to even use vim due to this reason ... Is there a way to tell vim to always ignore any roller actions from mouse middle roller button ( continue to sense the press of that roller yet ignore the roller )

I do not use any vim plugins

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 yet same vim bug happens on any Ubuntu for past many years

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 01 2022 09:16:32)
Included patches: 1-2269, 3612, 3625, 3669, 3741
```

In the mean time I am trying to always use `shift + insert` to paste instead of using the much more convenient mouse middle roller button press

Comment: the syntax to change options is `:set mouse=r`

Comment: `se paste` is a VERY bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to you question (it's instead a non-mouse work around), but
I have a function in my .vimrc to paste from the system clipboard (e.g. the `+`
and the `*` registers:

```
" paste from system clipboard
function! PasteFromRegister(reg, up_or_down, autoindent)
    set paste
    if a:up_or_down ==# 'up'
        call append(line('.')-1, '')
        execute "normal! k"
    elseif a:up_or_down ==# 'down'
        call append('.', '')
        execute "normal! j"
    endif
    execute 'normal! "'.a:reg.'p'
    if a:autoindent ==# 'autoindent'
        execute 'normal! =='
    endif
    set nopaste
endfunction

" paste from system CTRL-C clipboard
nnoremap <LEADER>p :call PasteFromRegister('+', 'same', 'noautoindent')<CR>
nnoremap <LEADER>]p :call PasteFromRegister('+', 'down', 'autoindent')<CR>
nnoremap <LEADER>[p :call PasteFromRegister('+', 'up', 'autoindent')<CR>
" paste from system highlighted clipboard
nnoremap <LEADER>P :call PasteFromRegister('*', 'same', 'noautoindent')<CR>
nnoremap <LEADER>]P :call PasteFromRegister('*', 'down', 'autoindent')<CR>
nnoremap <LEADER>[P :call PasteFromRegister('*', 'up', 'autoindent')<CR>
```

#### Bonus

To copy from my vim (which I always run in the terminal) to my system
clipboard, I first yank it to the unnailed register, then call the following
function (it works by temporarily pasting the contents at the bottom of the
file - it's been in my .vimrc for a long time, now I wonder if there's a more
elegant way to copy the contents of one register to another...):

```
" run a command, but put the cursor back when it's done
function! Preserve(command, is_func)
    " save last search, and cursor position.
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    " Do the business:
    if a:is_func ==# 1
        execute a:command()
    else
        execute a:command
    endif
    " restore previous search history, and cursor position
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfunction

" copy contents of unnamed register to system CTRL-C clipboard
nnoremap <silent> <LEADER>y :call Preserve("normal! Gp\"+dGu", 0)<CR>
            \ :echo 'copied to CTRL-C clipboard'<CR>
" copy contents of unnamed register to system highlighted clipboard
nnoremap <silent> <LEADER>Y :call Preserve("normal! Gp\"*dGu", 0)<CR>
            \ :echo 'copied to highlight clipboard'<CR>
```

Comment: `execute "normal! j"` can be just `normal! j` or even `-`; similar for other cases. Also, if you’re putting from a register, I don’t think setting paste has any effect (it’s specifically for when you actually paste from a clipboard using OS controls in insert mode and don’t want the text to trigger anything in Vim). So something like `"*p'[=']` should do fine, though you may need to adjust to paste linewise (perhaps `:put *` then `'[=']`?)

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble! This part of my .vimrc hails from a time when I was less informed (and if it 'worked' I would declare success and leave it at that :) I'll play around with it and update the answer soon. Thanks once again.